# EditText View Invisible - Can you still get the text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can you get the text input from an EditText view  when the EditText view is INVISIBLE?

```
comment_et.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you should be able to. There is no reason it should restrict you at all because it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've managed to find a solution to this yet, but I've had mixed results with the OS and invisible Views.

I have an app which is linked to a bluetooth barcode scanner (HID interface). And I used an `EditText` to receive input (saved me opening bluetooth sockets etc, cheap and nasty I know, but worked!). This worked fine all the time the View was visible, because being the only input control on the Activity, the OS automatically gave it focus to receive the input. However, as soon as the view was hidden, input wouldn't be accepted, no matter how hard I tried. Even manually giving the view focus, resulted in no input strings.

My work around (and it's terribly pre-school, but does the job), was to set the EditText Aplha value to 0, for fully transparent (I also set the text colour to white for good measure) and it all works lovely!

Just FYI n' all that. The visibility is a little odd, so you may have to toy with it, to get it to work they way you need.

Hope this helps someone out!

Comment: Ok, this is interesting but my question was about Getting the text not Setting the text